How to fix angular broken installation on Windows?
Platform is Windows 10. I have installed the latest nodejs (v20). Then I followed the installation manual:
npm install -g @angular/cli@17
And when I ran the command ng I get the next error:
C:\Users\Work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js:20
);
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

I have opened up ng.js in a text editor, and at line 20 I see this code:
console.error(
'This is the external Angular CLI, but you appear to be running in google3. There is a separate, internal version of the CLI which should be used instead. See http://go/angular/cli.',
);

I assume it does not like the extra coma after the end of the string. But I have no idea what could be wrong. I have tried older version of nodejs (v18) with older version of angular (v16), same error.

if you just use npm install -g @angular/cli without specifying the version, is there still the same error?
the latest version is 18, 17 is deprecated as described here https://v17.angular.io/cli?redirected_from=17

It happens with @angular/cli, too.

Seems like no expert knows the answer to this problem. Really disappointed in open source software! How can a release version be shipped like this. Stupid open source.
